# Why JTabbedPane does not respond to click on the tab?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have created one JTabbedPane with 3 tabs. 
When i switching to different tabs stateChang does not responds to click. 
when i put debug mark to my code in side public void `stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) { }`, i see no effect after click.

**What can be the reason and how can i fix it?**

```
public class TabbedPanChangeListener implements ChangeListener {
        ConfigToolScannersPanel panel;
        List<String> artikels = GenericsUtil.makeList();
public TabbedPanChangeListener(ConfigToolScannersPanel configToolScannersPanel) {
        this.panel = configToolScannersPanel;
}

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    WebTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (WebTabbedPane) e.getSource();
    int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
    String titel = sourceTabbedPane.getTitleAt(index);
    File dirconfig  = new File("C:\\tmp\\config");
    File dirPictures = new File("C:\\tmp\\Pictures");
    File diraxi = new File("C:\\tmp\\");
    File artikels = new File("C:\\tmp\\artikels.csv");

    if (dirconfig.exists()) {
        if (titel.equalsIgnoreCase("ftp")) {                
            panel.updateUI();
        } else if (titel.equalsIgnoreCase("Picture")) {
            setSelectedFileToNull();
            BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) panel.pictureTabPanel.getLayout();
            panel.pictureTabPanel.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.WEST));
            panel.pictureTabPanel.add(FileList.getGui(dirPictures.listFiles(), true, panel), BorderLayout.WEST);
            panel.pictureTabPanel.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH));
            panel.pictureTabPanel.add(FileList.getGui(diraxi.listFiles(), false, panel), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            panel.pictureTabPanel.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));

            // *** Add and remove from tool bar ***
            visibaleInvisibale(false);
            panel.btnDelete.setVisible(true);
            panel.btnDelete.setAction(new DeletePictureAction(panel));
            panel.btnAdd.setVisible(true);
            panel.btnAdd.setAction(new AddPictureAction(panel));
            panel.updateUI();
        } else if (titel.equalsIgnoreCase("dienst")) {

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Why JTabbedPane does not respond to click on the tab?"* Perhaps a better question is, why would you need to detect such change?  I've written at least 10 GUIs including `JTabbedPane` instances, and never needed to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you called this line in your code?

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new TabbedPanChangeListener(configToolScannersPanel));
```

Comment: Well spotted! And easy to forget. :-)